# Authorizing access through htaccess with both http and https

Tags: apache, .htaccess, https, lamp

I've searched for solutions and not finding a clear answer - It's a little out of my field but I need to find an answer in a pinch.

I use an .htaccess to verify and allow access to certain webpages from outside links.
here's a sample of what I use:

```
AuthUserFile /dev/null
AuthGroupFile /dev/null

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://www.website_abc.com/
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://www.website_xyz.com/

RewriteRule /* http://www.mysite.com/denied_message.php [R,L]
```

this works as I want it to - I list the sites that I want to access and park .htaccess in a root directory.

My problem is when someone is linking from HTTPS it block's them even if they are in the list (and I tried putting https in the list as well).
I found various answers but none that I fully understood or that did the trick.

one was using :

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
```

but that allowed anyone in from any location.

Can someone spell this out for me?

apache / LAMP

Thanks!

Comment: Just as a side note, that rewrite condition directs all of the traffic to https.  So if your other rewrite conditions don't match on https, then it won't work.  Someone more experienced will have to comment on what those new rewrite conditions will be.  Is there a reason you don't want to use a script such as php to do this? It would be super easy in php. I don't know if something at this level can be done in the htaccess.

Comment: It's one of those "it's just the way it's been done" type of projects.  _It would be super easy in php_ - I'm open to the php alternative (and more familiar) as long as I can continue to add new incoming sites to the list etc.

Comment: Yeah, I would say you're best off using PHP and controlling everything based of the $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']

Comment: Now I'm wondering if there's a setting a in apache config that needs to be looked at because, I believe there has the same issue capturing https in HTTP_REFERER - I'll need to refresh my memory and take a look at that. Thanks!

Comment: I also think the original attraction to using the htaccess approach was protecting everything inside a directory level in one shot.

Comment: You could have the htaccess redirect to your php script that then redirects if the referrer has access.

Answer (score 2):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
```

This adds a condition that the actual request for your site is through HTTPS. You only want to match the referer. I'm not sure what you've tried as far as adding `https://` versions of what you have in your referer checks, but this works when I put them in a blank htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://www.website_abc.com/
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://www.website_xyz.com/
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https://www.website_abc.com/
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https://www.website_xyz.com/

RewriteRule /* http://www.mysite.com/denied_message.php [R,L]
```

Comment: I did try that approach but those https users get blocked & redirected to the "denied message". It may also be some restriction on their end that I don't have control over so I need to find another way.